# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL in chrome extension v3 when using messages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, plugins, web-extension

Here is a minimal extension for chrome in v3:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test extension",
  "icons": {
    "48": "dark.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "button.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "dark.png",
    "default_title": "Test"
  }
}
```

**button.js**

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  console.log('clicked')
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { value: false })
});
```

The [API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) seems quite clear in the doc. So I don't understand why, when I press the plugin button, I get weird errors:

```
extensions.js:4187 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
    at ExtensionsErrorPageElement.onSelectedErrorChanged_ (extensions.js:4187:2827)
    at Object.runObserverEffect [as fn] (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:37568)
    at runEffectsForProperty (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:37087)
    at runEffects (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:36604)
    at ExtensionsErrorPageElement._propertiesChanged (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:52973)
    at ExtensionsErrorPageElement._flushProperties (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:26564)
    at ExtensionsErrorPageElement._flushProperties (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:51737)
    at ExtensionsErrorPageElement._invalidateProperties (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:51534)
    at ExtensionsErrorPageElement._setProperty (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:51459)
    at ExtensionsErrorPageElement.Object.defineProperty.set (polymer_bundled.min.js:1:24863)
onSelectedErrorChanged_ @ extensions.js:4187
runObserverEffect @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
runEffectsForProperty @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
runEffects @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
_propertiesChanged @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
_flushProperties @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
_flushProperties @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
_invalidateProperties @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
_setProperty @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
Object.defineProperty.set @ polymer_bundled.min.js:1
```

What am I missing?

*This is on Chromium Version 100.0.4896.75 (Build officiel) snap (64 bits)*

Comment: The code you've posted isn't related to the error. BTW you should use `chrome` instead of `browser`.

Comment: Damn it, that was the issue... What a weird message to tell me that

Comment: Now I get `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: I'll open another issue. This might help someone doing the same mistake

Comment: That's because you need to have a content script running in the tab if you want to send a message there. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: I have one. I just removed it because I had the other bug before. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71848934/uncaught-in-promise-error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does

Comment: By the way, if you want to make a proper answer I'll accept it.

Comment: IDK, almost a typo problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same exception but with another reason.

So, i see the possible solution(how to get real error message).

I've set breakpoint on failed line and check the runtimeError message.

Can be usefull for somebody.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

1. Please remove node modules or take a clone of the repo in the new folder
2. install node (npm install)
3. npx cypress open

it works perfectly.