# How to handle reactjs error that happens on page load?

Tags: reactjs

On the start of a js react application I have the following error:

```
commons.js:2 Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE isLogsEnabled null
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE options getValues
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
update @ commons.js:2
C @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE options getValues
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
update @ commons.js:2
ve.onUpdate.e.<computed>.O @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE contextMenu createContextMenu
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
send @ commons.js:2
setContextMenuItem @ commons.js:2
enable @ commons.js:2
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE tabClipper initCompleted
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE options getValue
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE options getValue
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.then (async)
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.then (async)
update @ commons.js:2
C @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.then (async)
update @ commons.js:2
ve.onUpdate.e.<computed>.O @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
send @ commons.js:2
setContextMenuItem @ commons.js:2
enable @ commons.js:2
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.catch (async)
_sendMessageToExtension @ commons.js:2
sendToExtension @ commons.js:2
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.then (async)
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
commons.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
Promise.then (async)
Le @ commons.js:2
168 @ commons.js:2
l @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
l.O @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
(anonymous) @ content.js:1
```

I have commented all of my components and error still happens. It happens when the page is loaded, I don't need to do anything, it is displayed several seconds after every refresh of the web page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For me the problem turned out to be an add-on for Google chrome called 'Evernote'. Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem with Edge on Mac. Solution:

Enable only on click (which reloads the page before the extension is available):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The issue for me was indeed related to Evernote Web Clipper. A more permanent option than simply allowing the extension to read site data on click would be to try whitelisting `www.evernote.com` in your ad blocker of choice (if using one). I was also running the uBlock Origin extension and once whitelisting Evernote the errors ceased. It's likely a recent conflict introduced between the two extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Adblock for Youtube generates this problem for me